# Table seems empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json file:

```
[
    {"cat1":"A1","cat2":"B1","cat3":10},
    {"cat1":"A2","cat2":"B2","cat3":20},
    {"cat1":"A3","cat2":"B3","cat3":30}
]
```

And I need 2 array content:

```
["A1","A2","A3"]
[10,20,30]
```

My script should do the work:

```
var tab1 = [];
var tab2 = [];
var tab3 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

$.getJSON("myjsonfile.json", function(json) {
    $.each( json, function( key, value ) {
        tab1[key] = value["cat1"];
        tab2.push(value["cat1"]);
    });
});
```

But it doesn't.

```
console.log(tab1[0]); // undefined
console.log(tab2[0]); // undefined
console.log(tab3[0]); // 0
```

I don't understand why

Comment: `$.getJSON` is asynchronous! Put the `console.log`s inside the callback at right after the `$.each`!

Comment: But how can I get my data in my 2 tables, outside of getJSON ?

Comment: *"outside of getJSON"* ... you don't...consume  the data within the complete callback or promise chain. That is how asynchronous programming works

Comment: You wrap the code that uses the two arrays in a function and then call that function when `$.getJSON` finishes it's work (call the function right after `$.each` in the callback of `$.getJSON`)! Do you want me to post an example?

Comment: Indeed, thanks @ibrahim